# jQuery Accordion with clickable headings and expand on icon click

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to find a jQuery menu that works the way I need. All the examples I've found online seem to use a hashed href link for the heading and open to show the li content on click.

I started off using this example,
http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Multilevel-Accordion-Menu-Plugin-For-jQuery-vmenu/
 but soon realised the shortcomings.

Because my headings are top level categories and the li is a set of sub categories I need to be able to have the main heading clickable to open that href, and then have the open icon be the click to slide out the li's.

Has anyone seen such an accordion menu?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this example where parent menu items can be proper clickable links

http://www.jqueryrain.com/?0xnaZzRG